# MikTex Install missing "miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma"

Tags: installing

I have tried installing MikTex at least 6 times and I keep getting a "remote file not found" error for the file "miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma" during the download process. I'm trying to install the full 64 bit version using file setup-2.9.5721-x64.exe.

I'm using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m and Windows 10.  I did a reboot.

Here is a sample of sites reporting the file is missing.

downloading ftp://ctan.math.utah.edu/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma (expecting 441554 bytes)...

downloading http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma (expecting 441554 bytes)...

downloading ftp://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma (expecting 441554 bytes)...

downloading ftp://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma (expecting 441554 bytes)...

Comment: Please use another installer.  Following question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266606/lzma-decoder-error check the comments. Your used installer  `setup-2.9.5721-x64.exe` has a bug.

Comment: The 32 bit version installed properly.

Comment: The problem seems to be that this `miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma` the installer tries to download does not exist on any mirror and I could fine no mention of in anywhere on the net either (though one CTAN report mentions it, it seems to have been out there once). I suppose there is some misplaced config file or other in the installer.

Comment: This is definitely related to [MiKTeX Setup on Windows - Error 404](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267512/35864) where the problem occurs with the 32 bit installer.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to install version 2.9.5721 x64 with all the packages, then download the basic x64 installer. After installing MikTeX, run the Package Manager (Admin) and install all the missing packages (Edit->Select Installable Packages, then Tasks->Install).

The package manager does not try to install the missing miktex-urct-bin-x64.tar.lzma file, so there is no problem.

Comment: I got the 32 bit running, so I going to be happy with it.  Do you know if there is a better supported Latex program? (for Windows 10)